# Correct Syntax for a SPF record

Tags: domain-name-system, spf

I want to create a SPF record for multiple subdomains, but I have no clue how to write a correct syntax. Since I am writing an application and it is not yet running live so I cannot yet test it.

But I have a number of subdomains e.g. :
* api.myservice.com
* booking.myservice.com
* partner.myservice.com

I know how to make a record for a single domain.
v=spf1 mx ptr a:server01.hosting.com mx:api.myservice.com ip4:123.12.12.14 ~all

But now I would like to add all three or more domains in the SPF record, what would be the syntax for that?
Or can I simply add more PTR records?
I have heard it is strongly disadvised.

Comment: Your example shows an SPF record, not a PTR record. Which are you desiring to create?

Comment: Actually an SPF record.. This is what you get when a lot of people are talking around you and you are trying to focus and mix up words in your own head.. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

No adding PTR records is not a good way to validate domain ownership.

If you want to share a single spf record with multiple domains, you want to **include** them

```
@ IN TXT "v=spf1 mx ptr a:server01.hosting.com mx:api.myservice.com ip4:123.12.12.14 ~all"
api.myservice.com IN TXT "v=spf1 include:myservice.com -all"
booking.myservice.com IN TXT "v=spf1 include:myservice.com -all" 
partner.myservice.com IN TXT "v=spf1 include:myservice.com -all"
```

If you are hosting services that you may use for other companies, I would suggest a special record for those services separate from the business

```
@ IN TXT "v=spf1 mx a:server01.hosting.com mx:api.myservice.com ip4:123.12.12.14 ~all"
_spf IN TXT "v=spf1 ip4:192.0.2.0/24 ip6:2001:db8::/64 -all"
api.myservice.com IN TXT "v=spf1 include:_spf.myservice.com -all"
booking.myservice.com IN TXT "v=spf1 include:_spf.myservice.com -all" 
partner.myservice.com IN TXT "v=spf1 include:_spf.myservice.com -all"
```

the other option of having the `a:api.myservice.com` record for each service, also not a great idea due to 10 domain lookup caps.

- [Avoid using PTR Records](https://space.dmarcian.com/ptr-mechanisms-in-spf-records/), you know that the IP Address is, summarize them if you can (cdir notation)
- Do not exceed 10 Domain Lookup (don't use A/MX if you know the addresses of your mx and manage their A records)